# source code location in GCC debug binary

Tags: gcc, debugging, gdb

I have a a library built with debug info. I need to make a mapping between locations where this library was built and local sources for the debugging.

So I'm not sure how to extract from the binary this info: where this debug binary was built on the machine of this library developer.

I suppose objdump utility should be used, but I couldn't find proper parameter(s) for that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to extract from the binary this info: where this debug binary was built on the machine of this library developer.

The `info source` GDB command will tell you that. Example:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f1: file t.c, line 1.
Starting program: /tmp/junk/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:1
1   int main() { return 0; }
(gdb) info source
Current source file is t.c
Compilation directory is /tmp/junk
Located in /tmp/junk/t.c
Contains 1 line.
Source language is c.
Producer is GNU C 4.8.4 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fstack-protector.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```